# Error with docker-compose - image not supported?

Tags: docker-compose

What's wrong with the following spec? (Image parameter is here to tag resulting image).

version: '3'

```
services:
   foo:
      build:
         image: foo/bar
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
         context: .
```

System output:

```
services.foo.build contains unsupported option: 'image'
```

*Versions: docker-compose: 1.14.0; Docker: 17.06.0-ce*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“Image” needs to be at the same level as “build”.